How to keep repos in sync where the committer does not have access to the remote repo?
A is a consultant and does not have access to the organisation's private remote repo. B and C are employees of the organisation and have access to the private remote repo.
Initially, B sends a zip file of the repo to A via email. Then A makes commits to his local git and sends the change patches via email to B. B applies the patches to his local repo and pushes to the private remote repo. C does a git pull regularly.
Assuming only A makes the commits, can this model continue to work where B has to never again send the zip file of repo to A via email?

If the assumption ("only A makes the commits") is strictly adhered to, this can work. I would have selected git bundles as exchange medium rather than patch files, but that would not make a difference under the assumption.

Use git bundle.

Or set up a private repo somewhere on the web that user A can push directly to, then periodically pull that into the corporate repository. Unless some information is missing (e.g. there's stuff already in the repo that the consultant shouldn't see), this feels unnecessarily painful. And if there is stuff in the repo the consultant shouldn't see, consider refactoring the repo. Or using a subtree. Or...

Correct @j6t, only A will make the commits. Will definitely consider git bundle, but there is a possibility that the private remote repo does not accept user A and it is expected that B will only change the name / email of the commit. Hence easy as a patch.

@Chris The organisation does not want the repository to be hosted even in a private repo outside of the org. If they could, most problems would be solved :). Of course, all the contents of this specific  git repo is visible to the consultant and there are no issues with that.

@rsmoorthy, lovely... they realize that developer A will have a copy of the code on their workstation, right? This feels like something a bit of communication should be able to solve, but I've met folks who refuse to budge on stuff like this. Good luck.
